# Hotmail mete mis correos en spam (caso raro)

Tags: servidor, email, smtp, microsoft

Desde hace unas semanas estoy teniendo un problema que me preocupa bastante por el hecho de que no sé qué está pasando. Tengo un servidor dedicado que utilizamos como servidor de correo, el caso es que nunca tenemos problemas pero desde hace poco Hotmail nos ha metido en la lista negra de microsoft.

Esto a priori es tan fácil de solucionar como rellenar el siguiente formulario y solicitar que nos saquen de dicha lista: [https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/concern/AccountReinstatement?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0][1]

El caso es que he repetido esta acción en varias ocasiones y he recibido la misma respuesta... en resumen me dicen que revise las condiciones de Microsoft, que no estoy cumpliendo con algún punto pero claro, no te dicen qué es y cuando entras en dicha página todo es muy político y prácticamente nada es técnico.

Pra que os hagáis una idea, estamos dado de alta en el Junk Mail Reporting Program desde hace años, no estamos en ninguna lista negra, la reputación de nuestra IP es Neutral en todos los sitios que solicitamos un informe, **no hacemos envíos masivos nunca**, tenemos correctamente configurado nuestro certificado SSL, dkim, dmarc, dns inversa, etc, **tenemos un 10/10 en https://www.mail-tester.com y sinceramente ya no se me ocurre nada más qué hacer.**

Nuestro problema es que los correos llegan a las cuentas de microsoft, pero siempre como SPAM.

Además, he leído bastante sobre el tema y he visto que estas 2 líneas son importantes:

**X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;**

En este caso, no he encontrado la ayuda oficial de Microsoft donde explique qué siginifica EFV:NLI...

**X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;**

Y en este caso sí que encontré el significdo de BCL, que hace referencia a las quejas de los usuarios de hotmail, en nuestro caso es 0, el nivel más bajo, no tenemos quejas y aún así nos marcan como spam.

Les dejo el encabezado de un correo enviado desde nuestro servidor a Hotmail.com (por si alguien puede ayudarme).

GRACIAS!

```
Received: from MW2NAM10HT012.eop-nam10.prod.protection.outlook.com

 (2603:10a6:205::21) by AM0PR0502MB4066.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS

 via AM4PR05CA0008.EURPRD05.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Mon, 21 Oct 2019 11:04:55 +0000

Received: from MW2NAM10FT040.eop-nam10.prod.protection.outlook.com

 (10.13.154.56) by MW2NAM10HT012.eop-nam10.prod.protection.outlook.com

 (10.13.154.128) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,

 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.2367.14; Mon, 21 Oct

 2019 11:04:53 +0000

Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 82.223.111.17)

 smtp.mailfrom=alejada.com; hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)

 header.d=alejada.com;hotmail.com; dmarc=pass action=none

 header.from=alejada.com;

Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of alejada.com designates

 82.223.111.17 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;

 client-ip=82.223.111.17; helo=mail.alejada.com;

Received: from mail.alejada.com (82.223.111.17) by

 MW2NAM10FT040.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.13.155.158) with Microsoft SMTP

 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id

 15.20.2367.14 via Frontend Transport; Mon, 21 Oct 2019 11:04:52 +0000

X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker:

 OriginalChecksum:C254604FB8277E3C713A1046AD5D7C1C28E3AD2DCB917018A976FAF5D8F17CED;UpperCasedChecksum:61A7BAA3EC40E53D708D0A4C7ACBA44347F8242601F25489A6CB7776BF31DFD8;SizeAsReceived:1197;Count:12

Received: from [192.168.1.57] (static-105-251-130-217.ipcom.comunitel.net [217.130.251.105])

    by mail.alejada.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id C00DC1F5C77

    for <alejadapruebas@hotmail.com>; Mon, 21 Oct 2019 12:04:50 +0100 (BST)

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=alejada.com;

    s=default; t=1571655891;

    bh=8Dm+MRSGn4qzggLuXkSktBUgvQ0q6pMGfXX/rQkbXMs=; l=21576;

    h=From:Subject:To;

    b=eYOzpkjA4qfTpbVhjEkqz6m3ixKk71Di6KdtlA4GcHmrQAKygPwWhkQD7dxqKA6/F

     dVTwaqtAgMSCCyHoZrmGO/4b+FzE4xWyy08TmKE+X3gs/RqDNQP5YRbOFF6xe+mlYl

     JjCee4QZ3612ty0d7l0zaep/51iovlWtFw5yu2DQ=

Authentication-Results-Original: mail.alejada.com;    spf=pass (sender IP is

 217.130.251.105) smtp.mailfrom=ancor.web@alejada.com smtp.helo=[192.168.1.57]

Received-SPF: pass (mail.alejada.com: connection is authenticated)

From: Ancor Santos <ancor.web@alejada.com>

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

    boundary="Apple-Mail=_FEF70158-D5F7-4251-B4ED-245D687DEB73"

Subject: Testeo

Message-Id: <D04E6BF3-FE8C-42D6-B9BD-20A503C53A8F@alejada.com>

Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 12:04:49 +0100

To: alejadapruebas@hotmail.com

X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.3445.104.11)

X-IncomingHeaderCount: 12

Return-Path: ancor.web@alejada.com

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 21 Oct 2019 11:04:52.4120

 (UTC)

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:

 278d5a35-0802-4d4f-02fa-08d756167f79

X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0

X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming

X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:

 MW2NAM10FT040.eop-nam10.prod.protection.outlook.com

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous

X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email

X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 10/21/2019 11:03:59 AM

X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 278d5a35-0802-4d4f-02fa-08d756167f79

X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: MW2NAM10HT012:

X-MS-Exchange-PUrlCount: 1

X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true

X-Sender-IP: 82.223.111.17

X-SID-PRA: ANCOR.WEB@ALEJADA.COM

X-SID-Result: PASS

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2

X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;

X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Oct 2019 11:04:52.2058

 (UTC)

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 278d5a35-0802-4d4f-02fa-08d756167f79

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet

X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:

 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: MW2NAM10HT012

X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:02.8491856

X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.2347.014

X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:

    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;ENG:(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900115)(4920090)(6350004)(4950130)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;

X-Message-Info:

    qoGN4b5S4yoMXhLFNSPyvy4ZqIgdkVYX14tHolpNspoKen/8NQ52FQKJbns7hCA5iOIX0y5yEPGvzObOe75uqcPg5KI1vgheWw36/znavJEggifFcJyDb38erI04FoMifKDYIkTA7107O2qdxtF8xvc3hPIEDZjXbTDTajQxB6qw+/CoeAkEWD936VPNG0daWQXUdUEGNUJ8IsEcIWYWDQ==

X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02

X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:

    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

MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: Llegate y mira si esta en alguna blacklist,

Comment: Eso está más que controlado, no está en ninguna lista negra, es en la propia lista de Hotmail... pero no hay forma de que nos den indicaciones.

Comment: Buenas Joel, tuve el mismo problema hace un tiempo. Intenta rellenar este formulario: (no es el que dices en la descripción) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=635714983457075069 Intenta comunicarte con la gente de uk antes que Spain. :)

Comment: Hola @DavidCreusLibrero! Voy a intentarlo a ver si hay suerte, porque ya he perdido toda esperanza. Gracias!!